# Long network operation on Oreo

Tags: android, android-service, android-8.0-oreo, android-workmanager, jobintentservice

In my Android application the user has an option of using the application in offline mode. When the user opts to enter the offline mode, I download all the content from the server(which might take even upto 7 minutes) for offline usage. The usage of the application henceforth is dependent on the download of offline content. 
I am using a service to download the offline content. But the service may not work in Android 8 if the app goes to the background. So what is the best approach to download the offline content for Android 8? Is it a `foreground service` or `JobIntentService` or a `WorkManager`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anything that is backed by `JobScheduler` — which includes `JobIntentService` and `WorkManager` — has a 10-minute limit. You indicate that your work may take up to 7 minutes, which makes me somewhat nervous.

In the short term, make your existing service be a foreground service, as that will keep your code working (other than any problems that Doze mode might impose).

If your 7-minute download work is really a series of smaller things that add up to 7 minutes, you might eventually migrate to `WorkManager`. Divide your work into smaller chunks and set up chained work with `WorkManager`, so you are certain to not go over the 10-minute limit for any of those chunks of work. Plus, `WorkManager` lets you establish constraints to say that your work should only be performed if you have an Internet connection. Right now (late August 2018), though, `WorkManager` is only `1.0.0-alpha07`, so I would not ship a product based on `WorkManager` until it at least reaches a `1.0.0` final version.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So you mean I make the existing service a foreground service in Android 8 and  a normal service below Android 8?

Comment: @DevAndroid: I would consider making it a foreground service on all versions, but that is up to you.

Answer (score 0):

The best approach would be to use [WorkManager](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/). As stated in the docs that:

> WorkManager is intended for tasks that require a guarantee that the
>   system will run them even if the app exits, like uploading app data to
>   a server, or downloading data from server.

The benefits of using WorkManager over services includes handling of doze, standby, battery optimizations and constraint execution etc.

You can schedule a worker with WorkManager to download data for your app from server, and once data is available, you can go on with your offline mode.

Comment: But if I use a `WorkManager` the work may not be executed immediately since Android system might club several works from different apps to be executed in a bunch. And in such a case the user is blocked from using the app since the offline content is not yet downloaded